# video stitch impossible to open path Invalid data found when processing input

Tags: javascript, node.js, video, ffmpeg

hope you all are healthy and safe,
so currently I am trying to use video-stitch NPM package for merge couple of videos together so here is my approach

```js
const videoStitch = require("video-stitch");
const videoConcat = videoStitch.concat;

try {
  // merge
  videoConcat({
    silent: false,
  })
    .clips([
      {
        fileName:
          "E:\\WS\\Projects\\vitok\\videos\\source\\6999919482068077826.mp4",
      },
      {
        fileName:
          "E:\\WS\\Projects\\vitok\\videos\\source\\7010852541999205637.mp4",
      },
    ])
    .output("test.mp4") //optional absolute file name for output file
    .concat()
    .then((outputFileName) => {
      console.log(`ouput: ${outputFileName}`);
    });
} catch (error) {
  console.log("error", error);
}
```

as you can see this is just a test so I am using absolute hard coded paths ..etc this works fine and incredibly fast. until I tried to use this useful function into a Node.js API I just copied same code to a function and hook it into one of my API end points and also made sure all paths are valid but I got this error log

```
ffmpeg version N-103968-g9fbe54e4b2-20211003 Copyright (c) 2000-2021 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 10-win32 (GCC) 20210408
  configuration: --prefix=/ffbuild/prefix --pkg-config-flags=--static --pkg-config=pkg-config --cross-prefix=x86_64-w64-mingw32- --arch=x86_64 --target-os=mingw32 --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --disable-debug --disable-w32threads --enable-pthreads --enable-iconv --enable-libxml2 --enable-zlib --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-gmp --enable-lzma --enable-fontconfig --enable-libvorbis --enable-opencl --enable-libvmaf --enable-vulkan --disable-libxcb --disable-xlib --enable-amf --enable-libaom --enable-avisynth --enable-libdav1d --enable-libdavs2 --disable-libfdk-aac --enable-ffnvcodec --enable-cuda-llvm --enable-frei0r --enable-libglslang --enable-libgme --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopus --enable-libtheora --enable-libvpx --enable-libwebp --enable-lv2 --enable-libmfx --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-librav1e --enable-librubberband --enable-schannel --enable-sdl2 --enable-libsoxr --enable-libsrt --enable-libsvtav1 --enable-libtwolame --enable-libuavs3d --disable-libdrm --disable-vaapi --enable-libvidstab --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxavs2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzimg --enable-libzvbi --extra-cflags=-DLIBTWOLAME_STATIC --extra-cxxflags= --extra-ldflags=-pthread --extra-ldexeflags= --extra-libs=-lgomp --extra-version=20211003
  libavutil      57.  7.100 / 57.  7.100
  libavcodec     59. 10.100 / 59. 10.100
  libavformat    59.  5.100 / 59.  5.100
  libavdevice    59.  0.101 / 59.  0.101
  libavfilter     8. 11.100 /  8. 11.100
  libswscale      6.  1.100 /  6.  1.100
  libswresample   4.  0.100 /  4.  0.100
  libpostproc    56.  0.100 / 56.  0.100
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0000025e87d6d880] Format mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 detected only with low score of 1, misdetection possible!
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0000025e87d6d880] moov atom not found
[concat @ 0000025e87d6c480] Impossible to open 'E:\\WS\\Projects\\vitok\\videos\\source\\6999919482068077826.mp4'
C:\Users\Abdel\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp-10992iQXU7FqWElTK.txt: Invalid data found when processing input
(node:10992) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: undefined
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
(node:10992) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:10992) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

I am not sure what is the problem, but for some reason its not running when I hook it to an API endpoint and works otherwise, I also tried to copy same function and run it when the API starts and it also worked, but when I try to use it in a API end point function it just crashes giving me the error above.

Am I doing anything wrong here? thanks in advance

Comment: Similar - https://superuser.com/questions/718027/ffmpeg-concat-doesnt-work-with-absolute-path, tldr: use forward slashes for the paths.

Comment: It  works with both forward slash and back slash but not with any when i hook it to api end point

Comment: Check out the other suggestions there.

Comment: do you think i should get some kind of permissions to access the API files or maybe the files paths changes  for some reason when I hook it to the api end point

Comment: on the question you mentioned above they use the cli tool I use a npm package which wraps the cli i guess

Comment: Yeah, same FFMPEG error though.

Comment: yeah same error